# Kannel SMS Gateway configuration on Windows platform

Tags: windows-7, configure, sms-gateway, kannel

How to configure Kannel SMS Gateway in Windows 7 ? I have no idea about this. Kannel site it self provide only the configuration for Linux platforms :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am not sure if would work directly on Windows 7 but i was able to get mine working via Windows Virtual PC

A. Create A new Windows Virtual PC

B. Download CentOS and install it on Windos Virtual PC (So many tutorials on you tube)

C. When your server is setup ... there is a nice tutorial here http://www.creativelodge.net/internet/how-tos/install-kannel-sms-gateway-in-centos-5/ but use use `yum install kannel` and use the tutorial to configure kannel

You would have kannel up and running on a Windows 7 perfectly

I hope this helps

Thanks

EDIT: Above link does not work. The working link is [Install Kannel SMS gateway in Centos 5](http://enbeeone3.com/install-kannel-sms-gateway-in-centos-5/)